# How can I make this recursive function save its content into a linked list?

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, filesystems

the following code opens a path and recursively reads through the directories and prints the files within it. At the moment it just prints the path to the directory and then every file within it but I would like to implement a linked list that will contain 1 char* variable that contains the full path to every file visited.

Here's the code :

```
#include <dirent.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>

void show_dir_content(char * path)
{
    DIR * d = opendir(path);                
    if(d==NULL) return;                     
    struct dirent * dir;                        
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)      
    {
        if(dir-> d_type != DT_DIR)          // if the type is not directory just print it
            printf("\t%s\n",dir->d_name);
        else
            if(dir -> d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(dir->d_name,".")!=0 && strcmp(dir->d_name,"..")!=0 )   // if it is a directory
            {
                char d_path[255];                               // here I am using sprintf which is safer than strcat
                sprintf(d_path, "%s/%s", path, dir->d_name);
                printf("%s\n",d_path);
                show_dir_content(d_path);                       
            }
    }
    closedir(d);                                        
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    show_dir_content(argv[1]);
    return(0);
}
```

The struct used for the linked list can be quite simple such as :

```
typedef struct search search;
struct search {
    char *path;
    char *fileName;
    char *fullPathToFile;
    search *next;
};
```

I'm just having a difficult time using mallocs for the struct and creating the actual linked list within the recursive function. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Too broad question. Please be specific on what is the exact problem you are having.

Comment: @user694733 my problem is specified at the end of the question.

Comment: You listed vague list of problems. You managed to define structure type. What your next step? Assuming it is allocating memory for it with `malloc`, what is the problem you are having? Compilation error message? Break your problem down to smaller problems, until you have a clear question that we can answer.

Comment: @user694733 Okay so I tried being less vague. [Here is the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855178/recursive-function-linked-lists-sprintf-not-saving-variable-into-struct-varia) I asked with a little bit more detail. Would you mind taking a look please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `search` node every time you find a file. Fill in the new node, then add it to the end of the list.

```
const char *path_format = "%s/%s";

// Modified to take a node ptr. This should be the last node in the list
// Returns a node ptr. This is the new last node in the list
search * show_dir_content(char * path, search *node)
{
    DIR * d = opendir(path);                
    if(d==NULL) return node;                     
    struct dirent * dir;                        
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)      
    {
        if(dir-> d_type != DT_DIR) {
            // Found a file. Alloc a new search node and fill in
            // (TODO: You should check the return from malloc for failure)
            search *new_node = malloc(sizeof(search));
            // TODO: copy all the names. Hint: strdup
            new_node->next = NULL;
            // Append to end of list
            node->next = new_node;
            // Update node pointer to now point to the new node
            node = node->next;
        }
        else
            if(dir -> d_type == DT_DIR && strcmp(dir->d_name,".")!=0 && strcmp(dir->d_name,"..")!=0 )   // if it is a directory
            {
                // Not sure 255 chars will be enough....
                char d_path[255];                               // here I am using sprintf which is safer than strcat
                sprintf(d_path, path_format, path, dir->d_name);
                printf("%s\n",d_path);
                // Make sure you update the node pointer to reflect any
                // changes made in the recursive call
                node = show_dir_content(d_path, node);
            }
    }
    closedir(d);
    // Return the last node (this may be same as input parameter if no files found                               
    return node;
}
```

Update `main` to create a root node and pass that to the function

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    search root = {0};
    show_dir_content(argv[1], &root);
    // Note that root is a dummy node.
    // The list actually begins at root->next

    // Also, before you exit, free all mem
    search *node = root.next, *next;
    while (NULL != node) {
        free(node->path);
        free(node->fileName);
        free(node->fullPathToFile);
        next = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I got a malloc error and an "Abort : trap 6" but Im looking through your response now.

Comment: I asked a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855178/recursive-function-linked-lists-sprintf-not-saving-variable-into-struct-varia). Could you please have a look?

Comment: You have to make a copy of the strings. Which means 1) allocating memory and 2) copying. [`strdup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) does this for you.

Comment: I'm so stupid for not reading the hint you left in the code. Thank you. It fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can modify your prototype to add a `struct search *` param wich gonna be the head pointeur of your list.

And when u need to put an element in your list just add a node in queue (or in head if u want but u need a `struct search **` instead of a simple pointer.
And then when u need to put an element just call the function which gonna create an element and place it where u want.
After that u will just give to every recursive call the `head ptr` of your list

Comment: Okay I will try to implement this. Thank you for the idea.